# Traversals for Java TreeMap

Tags: java, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Is it possible to perform a pre-order traversal/in-order traversal/post-order traversal/level-order traversal on a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) in Java without any additional classes or libraries?

Comment: The TreeMap is a map _internally implemented_ with a tree, but does not offer a "tree- like" API

Comment: If you are looking for a project doing tree traversal (in Java 8) without using any external library, you may want to jave a look at https://github.com/JavaChat/streems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over the entries of the `TreeMap` (i.e. iterating over the `Set` returned by `entrySet()`) will give you in-order traversal.

You can't, however, do pre-order or post-order traversal, since the `TreeMap.Entry` class, which is used to implement the tree structure, is not visible. If you try to cast the `Entry`s returned by `entrySet()` to `TreeMap.Entry`, you'll get the error: `The type TreeMap.Entry is not visible`.

Comment: Is there any other built-in class that offers the other traversals or has its entries visible?